# pip install. Requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pip

I have anaconda navigator and python 3.7 idle.

Now I want to pip install something on python 3.7 idle.
But it says "requirement already satisfied" on anaconda navigator.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is followed by [anaconda-issues issue 1429](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429)

For instance:

> If you only happen to have pip installed in your root env, and your root env is on your path, then yes a pip install will always (by coincidence) install into the root env
>
> After conda 4.4 we should add `. /data/wanggu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` into `.bashrc`.
>
> A good way to also do this imo is by creating the conda environment and installing a python version in it: `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x`
> This way if you pip install xx it will be installed in the environment path and not globally.
> It can also be helpful this way because you can have specific python versions in different environments as needed.